# How to copy file/folder permissions and ownerships from one folder to another (recursively)

Tags: permissions, git

How do I copy all the folder, subfolders and files permissions (recursively) from `/www_03062018` to my new `/www` ?

I came across [this question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/625673/clone-permissions-for-all-files-in-a-folder).

```
chmod --reference=RFile file
```

Which didn't help much, it did apply a change for the main folder `/www` but didn't apply on its subfolders and files.

I have tried:

```
chmod -R --reference=/www_03062018 /www
```

and it didn't work.

**My situation:**

I have 2 folders on my Ubuntu machine: `/www` and `/www_03062018`.

`/www` is a "git clone" from the production machine.

`/www_03062018` is my old directory that i used to work on and upload files via FTP.

I started to use GIT and when I clone a directory its folder ownerships and file accesses settings don't get cloned along with it.

Comment: Git does neither record permissions nor ownership except for the `x` bit. You need some other means to maintain those file attributes.

Comment: Yes i figured this out, i still have my backed up folder i used to work on, so i can copy its permissions tree maybe. if i can apply this to one folder, im sure there is a command that does that recursively @PerlDuck

Comment: And what is wrong with doing `cp -R --preserve /www /www_03062018`?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen because of the last part of my post. i explained why.

Comment: `-p` is not a valid command `chmod: invalid option -- 'p'
Try chmod --help for more information.` @PerlDuck

Comment: then there is `cp -R --attributes-only /www_03062018 /www`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen it just copied `/www_03062018` into `/www` as a new folder

Comment: Yes that was what i thought you were about so I posted a second command using `cp` that only copies the attributes over!

Comment: For CHMOD this worked: `find . -path ./.git -prune -or -exec chmod --reference '/www_03062018/{}' '{}' ';'` 
And for CHOWN this worked: 

`find . -path ./.git -prune -or -exec chown --reference '/www_03062018/{}' '{}' ';'`

Answer (score 2):

cd to the new directory which you want to give new permissions - in my case:

```
cd /www
```

For CHMOD this worked:

```
find . -path ./.git -prune -or -exec chmod --reference '/www_03062018/{}' '{}' ';'
```

And for CHOWN this worked:

```
find . -path ./.git -prune -or -exec chown --reference '/www_03062018/{}' '{}' ';'
```

Hope this helps others :) !